# Retrieving record by id is not working?

Tags: android, sqlite

Am trying to display the record based on user id but its diplaying the last updated record only cannot display the whole record based on id how can i achieve this here let me post my code:

Here is the code where i retrieve the record based on id:

```
  public List<Model_Task_List> getTaskListById(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Model_Task_List model_task_list=new Model_Task_List();
        String selectQuery =  " SELECT  " +
                Model_Task_List.KEY_id + "," +
                Model_Task_List.KEY_username + "," +
                Model_Task_List.KEY_subject + "," +
                Model_Task_List.KEY_task + "," +
                Model_Task_List.KEY_taskid  +"," +
                Model_Task_List.KEY_owner+
                " FROM " + Model_Task_List.KEY_table + " WHERE "   +  Model_Task_List.KEY_owner + "= " + id  + "";
        List<Model_Task_List>listobj=new ArrayList<Model_Task_List>();
        Model_Task_List modelobj=new Model_Task_List();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
           do {
               modelobj.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Model_Task_List.KEY_id))));
               modelobj.setUserName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Model_Task_List.KEY_username)));
               modelobj.setSubject(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Model_Task_List.KEY_subject)));
               modelobj.setTaskStatus(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Model_Task_List.KEY_task)));
               modelobj.setTaskID(cursor.getShort(cursor.getColumnIndex(Model_Task_List.KEY_taskid)));
               modelobj.setUserid(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Model_Task_List.KEY_owner)));
               listobj.add(modelobj);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return listobj;

    }
```

Here is the code where i set adapter :

```
model_task_lists=database_sf_app.getTaskListById(user_id)
taskadapter=new Task_List_Adapter(model_task_lists,getActivity()); recyclerView.setAdapter(taskadapter);
```

How can i sort this problem whether am doing it in right way

Comment: if your `id` is in string format , you need to concat it with quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem only your model class,You create a model class object only one time.
If you retrieve the all database record then create a new object everytime when record is fetched.

```
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
       do {
modelobj=new Model_Task_List();            modelobj.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Model_Task_List.KEY_id))));
           modelobj.setUserName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Model_Task_List.KEY_username)));
           modelobj.setSubject(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Model_Task_List.KEY_subject)));
           modelobj.setTaskStatus(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Model_Task_List.KEY_task)));
           modelobj.setTaskID(cursor.getShort(cursor.getColumnIndex(Model_Task_List.KEY_taskid)));
           modelobj.setUserid(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Model_Task_List.KEY_owner)));
           listobj.add(modelobj);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```